# Shifting the camera and setting a new scene when using Box2D

Tags: javascript, box2d, camera

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8eKp/4/show):

```
// START -- MOVE CAMERA
var p = new b2Vec2();
p = (ball.body.GetWorldCenter().x) * physics.scale;
pos.push(p);
var length = pos.length;

var s = (pos[length - 1] - pos[length - 2]); //in pixels

if ((halfwidth < (dw - p)) && (p > halfwidth)) {
    ctx.translate(-s, 0);
}
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codingowl.com/readblog.php?blogid=128), but the ball rendering is acting weird and slow.

I can't figure out how [this example](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/05/04/following-a-body-with-the-camera-in-box2d-the-smart-way/) did it. He used 3 variables (`stage`,`x`, `y`) that are undefined in the code he wrote. Also check out how the camera moves with the player in [this ImpactJS demo](http://impactjs.com/demos/physics/). I'd like to have that.

How can I do this?

Comment: please anyone give me a hint or anything !!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Which bit of those tutorials in these links are you looking to incorporate? What have you tried to isolate the problem you're having?

Comment: those tutorials are just demos for how i want the scene to be shifting i want just someone to provide me a simple example for how i can achieve that same functionality in my code  in `impact.js` example and `emanueleferonato` u see when the player move the camera move with it so smoothly  but in my code u see the weird slow behavior (at some point the whole scene start shaking )